# Use ValidateSet with the contents loaded from a CSV file

Tags: validation, powershell, csv, parameters

I really like the way that `ValidateSet` works. It proposes the options as a list while you type your Cmdlet in the PowerShell ISE.

I would like to know if it's possible to retrieve values from a CSV-file (`Import-CSV`) and use them in the `Param` block so they become available in the drop down box of the PowerShell ISE when constructing the Cmdlet arguments? A bit in the same way that `$Type` works now, but then with values from the import file.

```
Function New-Name {
Param (
    [parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateSet('Mailbox','Distribution','Folder','Role')]
    [String]$Type,
    [parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$Name
)
    Process { 'Foo' }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is something you can start with:

```
function New-Name {
    param (
        [parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Name
    )

    dynamicparam {
        $attributes = new-object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $attributes.ParameterSetName = "__AllParameterSets"
        $attributes.Mandatory = $true
        $attributeCollection = new-object -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $attributeCollection.Add($attributes)
        $values = @('MailBox', 'Tralala', 'Trilili') # your Import-Csv here
        $ValidateSet = new-object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($values)
        $attributeCollection.Add($ValidateSet)

        $dynParam1 = new-object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("Type", [string], $attributeCollection)
        $paramDictionary = new-object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
        $paramDictionary.Add("Type", $dynParam1)
        return $paramDictionary 
    }

     process { 'Foo' }
}
```

Credits where credits are due, this largely comes from the following [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/21/use-dynamic-parameters-to-populate-list-of-printer-names.aspx) from the Scripting Guy.
The code isn't pretty, but it does what you want.

[image: completion]

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is quite old, but with Powershell 6.2 and above you can use a .NET class at the beginning of the script and have the set controlled by a csv for example.

This article hear does an excellent job of explaining:
https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-validateset/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer TabExpansion++ module though this doesn't technically validate, it has some nice functionality...

Here's an example of an msbuild overloaded command to add some intellisense for projects

```
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName "msbuild" -ParameterName "target" -ScriptBlock {
    param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete, $commandAst, $fakeBoundParameter)

    $projectName = $fakeBoundParameter['project']
    $projectFile = Join-Path (Get-Location) $projectName
    $projectXml = [xml](Get-Content $projectFile)

    $targets = $projectXml.Project.Target | Where-Object { $_.Name.ToString().StartsWith($wordToComplete) }
    foreach($target in $projectXml.Project.Target)
    {
        New-CompletionResult -CompletionText "$($target.Name)"
    }
}
```