# PSCmdlet dynamic auto complete a parameter (like Get-Process)

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

In powershell some parameter have a dynamic auto complete behavior.
For Example, Get-Process the parameter Name. I can iterate trough all my processes with TAB.

[image: Powershell auto complete parameter]

**I want to use this behavior in my PSCmdlet.**

But the problem is, I only know how to do this with static auto complete valuee. See the example:

```
public class TableDynamicParameters
{
    [Parameter]
    [ValidateSet("Table1", "Table2")]
    public string[] Tables { get; set; }
}
```

Here an example how this is done with native powershell http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/21/use-dynamic-parameters-to-populate-list-of-printer-names.aspx

---

**It works**
thx to @bouvierr

```
public string[] Tables { get; set; }

public object GetDynamicParameters()
{
    if (!File.Exists(Path)) return null;

    var tableNames = new List<string>();
    if (TablesCache.ContainsKey(Path))
    {
        tableNames = TablesCache[Path];
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            tableNames = DbContext.GetTableNamesContent(Path);
            tableNames.Add("All");
            TablesCache.Add(Path, tableNames);
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }

    var runtimeDefinedParameterDictionary = new RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary();
    runtimeDefinedParameterDictionary.Add("Tables", new RuntimeDefinedParameter("Tables", typeof(String), new Collection<Attribute>() { new ParameterAttribute(), new ValidateSetAttribute(tableNames.ToArray()) }));

    return runtimeDefinedParameterDictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From MSDN: [How to Declare Dynamic Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/how-to-declare-dynamic-parameters)

Your `Cmdlet` class must implement the `IDynamicParameters` interface. This interface:

> Provides a mechanism for a cmdlet to retrieve parameters that can be added dynamically by the Windows PowerShell runtime.

EDIT:

The `IDynamicParameters.GetDynamicParameters()` method should:

> return an object that has properties and fields with parameter related attributes similar to those define in a cmdlet class or a RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary object.

If you look at this [link](https://martin77s.wordpress.com/2014/06/09/dynamic-validateset-in-a-dynamic-parameter/), the author is doing this in PowerShell. He creates at runtime:

- a new instance of `ValidateSetAttribute` with a **runtime** array of possible values
- He then creates a `RuntimeDefinedParameter` onto which he assigns the `ValidateSetAttribute`
- He returns a `RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary` containing this parameter

You can do the same in C#. Your `GetDynamicParameters()` method should return this `RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary` containing the appropriate `RuntimeDefinedParameter`.

Comment: This would allow for a second parameter to be added in the event another was specified. I don't see how this answers the OP's question of dynamically determining a potential value for a parameter.

Comment: @Matt I clarified my answer. the link I posted shows the technique. It's in PS, but it's all just .NET objects so you can do the same in C#, in the `GetDynamicParameters()` method.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177744/powershell-validateset) is a link to another SO post for the same thing. contains the Scripting guys link for the same solution.